# Merge values on multi-line columns on a Datagridview

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, winforms, datagridview

I have Visual Studio 2019. The project is a .Net Windows Form on C# on .Net Framework 4.8.

I have a Datagridview which shows some tables data from different databases (MS SQL and Postgresql).

I merge that databases, and the result is too long, so we can't fit it on a screen; but we have to see all the data available on that screen, which are more than 40 columns. Reduce the font size is not plausible.

So, the solution proposed was to merge some values on the same column in this way (See this example):

The actual data view:

[image: actual]

The way we need to view it:

[image: goal]

If you have any ideas or you know an alternative to Datagridview which allows that, please share them.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your solution to the problem… _” … and the result is too long, so we can't fit it on a screen; but we have to see all the data available on that screen, which are more than 40 columns. Reduce the font size is not plausible.”_ … may well work. However, from a user’s perspective, I can easily see the user struggling and possibly mixing up which value “belongs” to which field. It may help to color code the fields to help the user differentiate the data without some extra work. Another possible solution may be “transpose” the data. The columns would be the names, and the rows the data.

Comment: I can't change the color since the goal of the software has to be to show all the rows on default white, except when an alert makes a row blink on red when a mistake is done. The transpose solution (I guess it's the PIVOT function) is not really giving me the results I need... I'll keep trying... Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can customize your datagridview's row and column to get the Multi-line columns on a datagridview.

I assume that the datatable is the table from database.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            table.Columns.Add("Name");
            table.Columns.Add("Field1");
            table.Columns.Add("Field2");
            table.Columns.Add("Field3");
            table.Columns.Add("Field4");
            table.Columns.Add("Field5");
            table.Columns.Add("Field6");
            table.Columns.Add("Field7");
            table.Rows.Add("test1", 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7);
            table.Rows.Add("test2", 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7);
            table.Rows.Add("test3", 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7);
            dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersVisible = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < table.Columns.Count/2; i++)
            {
                dataGridView1.Columns.Add("","");
            }
            string[] columnNames = table.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
                                 .Select(x => x.ColumnName)
                                 .ToArray();
            int count = table.Columns.Count/2;
            var col1 = columnNames.Take(count).ToArray();
            var col2= columnNames.Skip(count).Take(count).ToArray();
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(col1);
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(col2);
            object[] arr;
            for (int i = 0; i < table.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                arr = table.Rows[i].ItemArray;
                var row1=arr.Take(count).ToArray();
                var row2 = arr.Skip(count).Take(count).ToArray();
                dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row1);
                dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row2);

            }
           
        }
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: In my environment (described on the question) I haven't got the Cast option on table.Columns neither Take/Skip options on arrays

Comment: @operamaxi, this is linq method. You can try add the code "using System.Linq;" in your code.

Comment: Sorry but I still couldn't test it, I'm working on too many projects at the same time. Anyway, I also think that adding the Linq will solve the problem. When I've tried it, i'll answer and proceed to validate the answer. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to reply, I have finally tested it and it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

After reviewing your question, I have to say that IMHO your solution is not giving much thought to the end user or if the code has to grab one of the values. Stacking fields into a single column “creates” two issues IMHO…One, as mentioned, is that the user is going to have to do extra work and check the order of the headers to distinguish which field value is which… a subtle yet (annoying) non intuitive extra step. Two, if the user is allowed to change fields or the code needs to grad a field, then, there is going to be extra work needed to differentiated which field goes with which value. Extra work for the user and extra work for the coder doesn’t sound like a good start.

Sorry about my rant. Fortunately, if you wanted to take a table as shown in the question, and turn it into a table as you describe, then the code below should do this. It basically creates “two” (2) field columns. Such that each column contains two fields. The code is hacky yet it is not too complicated I hope. I made numerous comments in the code. Some notes would be that, since we are adding two fields for each column and (as far as I know) a `DataGridView` won’t allow double column headers, the code does NOT use the column headers row and instead uses the first two rows of the grid for the two column headers. This will allow you to format the two rows to look like headers and/or color code if needed.

Lastly, a better solution IMHO. As previously mentioned a pivot will work, however, there are a couple of issues given how the data is stored in the original table. In a basic pivot where we switch rows and columns, the posted example would have three (3) columns… “Jim”, “Hugh” and “Terrance”. Then the number of rows would be (one (1) + however many fields/field columns). The extra “one” is the field “LastName.” Given this, it may look something like…

```
                   Jim       Hugh         Terrance
LastName           Carey     Jackman      Hill
Field1             1         a            N/A
Field2             2         b            N/A
      ……..
```

It would appear obvious that the “LastName” should go with the column header. Therefore, the transpose/pivot may look like…

```
                   Jim Carey      Hugh Jackman      Terrance Hill
Field1             1              a                 N/A
Field2             2              b                 N/A
      ……..
```

IMHO, this will be more intuitive for the user to identify fields and there should not be any extra coding if we need to reference a specific value. The picture below shows a complete example from the code below. Drop three (3) `DataGridViews` onto a form and paste my code. The top-left grid is the original data. The bottom-left grid is the transpose as per your requirements and finally, the grid on the right is the what I feel would work best considering your dilemma.

[image]

A note on the last grid on the right… Initially, like the column header rows in your solution, I had the fields as a column in the grid. It will not be difficult to change the code if you want this. However, the code currently adds the field names as “row headers” in the grid. Since the `DataTable` does not really have row headers, this addition had to be made “after” the data source was set and can be seen in the forms `Load` event. Again, it will not be difficult to move the field to an added column in the `DataTable`.

To make this example complete, below is code to create some test data. The incoming parameter `totalCols` will make `totalCols` columns in the `DataTable` for the "Field" values.

```
private DataTable GetDataFromDB(int totalCols) {
  DataTable dt = new DataTable();
  dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
  dt.Columns.Add("LastName", typeof(string));
  for (int i = 1; i <= totalCols; i++) {
    dt.Columns.Add("Field" + i, typeof(string));
  }
  DataRow curRow;
  string name;
  string lName;
  for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
    switch (i) {
      case 1:
        name = "Jim";
        lName = "Carrey";
        break;
      case 2:
        name = "Hugh";
        lName = "Jackman";
        break;
      default:
        name = "Terence";
        lName = "Hill";
        break;
    }
    curRow = dt.NewRow();
    curRow["Name"] = name;
    curRow["LastName"] = lName;
    if (i < 3) {
      for (int j = 2; j < dt.Columns.Count; j++) {
        curRow[j] = "N" + i + "F" + (j - 1);
      }
    }
    dt.Rows.Add(curRow);
  }
  return dt;
}
```

We will use three (3) global `DataTables`, one for each grid.

```
DataTable originalDT;
DataTable pivotDT1;
DataTable pivotDT2;
```

The load event that sets each grid to the proper `DataTable` and some specific formatting for each grid.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  originalDT = GetDataFromDB(45);
  dataGridView1.DataSource = originalDT;
  // pivot 1 - bottom left grid
  pivotDT1 = PivotTable(originalDT);
  dataGridView2.DataSource = pivotDT1;
  dataGridView2.DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
  dataGridView2.Rows[0].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Blue;
  dataGridView2.Rows[1].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Blue;
  dataGridView2.Rows[0].DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.White;
  dataGridView2.Rows[1].DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.White;
  dataGridView2.Columns[0].Frozen = true;
  // pivot 2 - right grid
  pivotDT2 = PivotTable2(originalDT);
  dataGridView3.DataSource = pivotDT2;
  int dgvRow = 0;
  // add column headers as row headers in the grid
  for (int i = 2; i < originalDT.Columns.Count; i++) {
    dataGridView3.Rows[dgvRow++].HeaderCell.Value = originalDT.Columns[i].ColumnName;
  }
  dataGridView3.RowHeadersWidthSizeMode = DataGridViewRowHeadersWidthSizeMode.AutoSizeToAllHeaders;
}
```

Finally, the two pivot/transform methods…

Using your solution and shown in the bottom-left grid…

```
private DataTable PivotTable(DataTable originalDT) {
  DataTable pivotDT = new DataTable();
  // the number of columns will be half the original number of columns
  int halfCols = Math.DivRem(originalDT.Columns.Count, 2, out int rem);
  // if there is a remainder then there is an odd number of columns and we need to add 1 col
  if (rem > 0) {
    halfCols++;
  }
  // add the columns to the pivot table
  for (int i = 0; i < halfCols; i++) {
    pivotDT.Columns.Add();
  }
  // the number of rows will be the number of original rows times 2
  // PLUS 2 additional rows for the headers
  for (int i = 0; i < (originalDT.Rows.Count * 2) + 2; i++) {
    pivotDT.Rows.Add();
  }
  // Add the two header rows from the column names
  int originalCol = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < halfCols; i++) {
    pivotDT.Rows[0][i] = originalDT.Columns[originalCol++].ColumnName;
    // if the original table had an odd number of columns
    // then the last column only had one field 
    // - there would never be a column without at least one field
    if (originalCol < originalDT.Columns.Count) {
      pivotDT.Rows[1][i] = originalDT.Columns[originalCol++].ColumnName;
    }
  }
  // finally add the rows from the original table.
  int pivotRow = 2;
  int pivotCol = 0;
  int curPivotRow;
  int curPivotCol;
  string value;
  for (int originalRow = 0; originalRow < originalDT.Rows.Count; originalRow++) {
    curPivotRow = pivotRow;
    curPivotCol = pivotCol;
    for (originalCol = 0; originalCol < originalDT.Columns.Count; originalCol++) {
      value = originalDT.Rows[originalRow][originalCol].ToString();
      if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value)) {
        value = "N/A";
      }
      pivotDT.Rows[curPivotRow][curPivotCol] = value;
      // if this is the first item then simply bump the pivot row
      if (curPivotRow < pivotRow + 1) {
        curPivotRow++;
      }
      else { // this is the second item -
             // we want the curpivot row to start back at the starting pivotRow
             // then move over a column for the next two columns in the original table
        curPivotRow = pivotRow;
        curPivotCol++;
      }
    }
    // new row in the original data start back at column 0 in the pivot table
    // and bump the row index by two since we added two rows
    pivotRow += 2;
    pivotCol = 0;
  }
  return pivotDT;
}
```

And my solution shown in the grid on the right.

```
private DataTable PivotTable2(DataTable originalDT) {
  DataTable pivotDT = new DataTable();
  for (int i = 0; i < originalDT.Rows.Count; i++) {
    pivotDT.Columns.Add();
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < originalDT.Columns.Count - 2; i++) {
    pivotDT.Rows.Add();
  }
  int pivotCol = 0;
  foreach (DataRow row in originalDT.Rows) {
    pivotDT.Columns[pivotCol++].ColumnName = row[0].ToString() + " " + row[1].ToString();
  }
  int pivotRow = 0;
  pivotCol = 0;
  string value;
  for (int i = 0; i < originalDT.Rows.Count; i++) {
    for (int j = 2; j < originalDT.Columns.Count; j++) {
      value = originalDT.Rows[i][j].ToString();
      if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value)) {
        value = "N/A";
      }
      pivotDT.Rows[pivotRow++][pivotCol] = value;
    }
    pivotCol++;
    pivotRow = 0;
  }
  return pivotDT;
}
```

Finally, I am not that proficient using SQL, however, I am betting it is possible to create an SQL procedure that will produce my solution directly from the data base.

Comment: Thank you very much for such a detailed and helpful answer.